# ANT target execution success or failure indicator

Tags: jenkins, ant

I am working as part of a testcase automation scenario where my testcases are written as ANT `<target>` calls and each `<target>` represents each testcase. Let's assume I have 10 `<target>` defined. I will use a shell script to call this 10 `<target>`.

I am looking for a way, after execution of shell script i should be able to see the result of which `<target>` call passed(Build successful) and which `<target>` call failed (Build Failed) in a consolidated way. Do we have any option in ANT to achieve this?.

Comment: Check the exit code?

Comment: Similar to that. Lets me explain the scenario. I am using Jenkins job->shell script to trigger this <target> calls. Now In Jenkins i am seeing all the console message of the <target> call execution. But my use case is to have a consolidated report kind of output where it just need to show the number of <target> call failures and success